# CSS is not loading properly until refresh the page manually

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

My page's CSS is not loaded properly until refresh it, as shown in the following pictures. I've been surfing on the internet to solve this issue but couldn't find a solution, and source of the problem.

[First enter the page,](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BalkjyIVX3ErUjYmBB-ZctRQa5CV9QFL/view?usp=sharing)
[After refreshing the page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1We9yN9GBCR8oCPSbJzWJhoi868iiuuQ-/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If you include your styles and script by `wp_enque....` functions you need update versions your files than all browsers clear this cached files.